# Appengine: db.Model.get_by_id(id) does not work

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have some Ice-entities in my datastore.
When I run the following on the admin-webInterface

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Ice(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    description = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

for ice in Ice.all():
    print ice.key().id()
    print Ice.get_by_id(ice.key().id())
```

I always get:

```
4
None
5
None
6
None
7
None
8
None
9
None
10
None
11
None
12
None
13
None
14
None
15
None
16
None
17
None
18
None
19
None
20
None
```

Why?

Comment: I tried it on my home-mac... It had a clean datastore. Now it works...
Will try it at work tomorrow.

Comment: Your syntax looks fine. If it's failing, something else is awry.

Answer (score 1):

You would see exactly this behaviour if your `Ice` entities are child entities. The id field is not globally unique - only unique for a given kind and parent.

Answer (score -1):

You're using `Ice.key()`. Did you want [`Model.get_by_key_name()`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_by_key_name) instead?

Answer (score -1):

I have also recently experienced problems with the get_by_id method. I am using SDK 1.7.6. The problem was that the new dev_appserver creates datastore entity id values larger than Javascript can handle. I can be fixed in your dev environment by using sequential IDs.

Use this link for further explanation [Issue 1.7.6](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9030&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Lo)

When I searched for a solution to the problem I got confused with all feedback about a missing parent. I had no missing parent relation and still get_by_id did not work! I hope this answer can save some time for people with the same problem...

Comment: i do not really understand why you would think that javascript has something to do with this answer.